# How do I make a Button become normal after a window has been closed?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def OptionsMenu():
    OptionsWin = Tk()
    options.config(state=DISABLED)

options = Button(win, text="Options", command=OptionsMenu)
```

Here is the code im trying to do. I want the Options button to be disabled after the options menu has appeared (which I did). But i want the button re-enabled after the options menu has been closed. How do I do that?

Comment: Is that your whole code?

Comment: @JacksonPro no there is more code but i didnt want to post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First don't use multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Use `Toplevel()` in `OptionsMenu()`.  You can bind `<Destroy>` event to a callback to enable back the <kbd>Options</kbd>:

```py
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

def OptionsMenu():
    options.config(state=DISABLED)
    OptionsWin = Toplevel() # use Toplevel instead of Tk
    # The callback of "<Destroy>" event will be triggered when the window is closed.
    OptionsWin.bind("<Destroy>", lambda e: options.config(state=NORMAL))

options = Button(win, text="Options", command=OptionsMenu)
options.pack()

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you explain your code to me?
i need to know how did you did it.
im really bad at python so please dont be angry at me.

Comment: Which parts you don't understand?

Comment: the bind part.
i really dont understand that.

Comment: `bind()` function is used to bind an event to a callback which will be executed when such event is happened on the target widget.  There are many events, `<Destroy>` is one of them that will be triggered when the target widget is being destroyed.  See doc on [bind](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/bind.htm).

Comment: Thanks Man, appreciate it.